# Can I access my ftp server through path such as \\192.xx.xx.xx?

Tags: windows, ftp, windows-xp, ipc

I build a ftp server based on serv-u winxp, now I can access it by ftp://192.xx.xx.xx, can I access it through path such as \192.xx.xx.xx directly? Direct means can doing it by explorer 's path, similar to the windows share folder, by I want to redirect the target.

Comment: Did you try doing that? what was the result?

Comment: Your question is ot clear but as for as i understand i think NO because you must have to specify protocol.what do you mean by "access direclty" ?

Comment: @freak Direct means can doing it by explorer 's path, similar to the windows share folder, by I want to redirect the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `\\192.xx.xx.xx` is the URI syntax for Windows file sharing. That is not the same as FTP.

The only way to get to an FTP server from Explorer is to state the protocol, using the `ftp://` URI syntax.

Comment: Can I redirect the URI to another target?